# I want to make a clearable search field. Where did I make a mistake?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a clearable search field. when I click on the cross button I want to reset the value of the input

```js
function clear() {
  var a = document.getElementById('searchField');
  a.value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="searchGroup">
  <input type="text" id="searchField">
  <button onclick="clear()">&times;</button>
</div>
```

I expect the input should be reset with no value.

Comment: You may also want to see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the function name from `clear` to something else. Though deprecated it may be calling [document.clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear)

```js
function clearInput() {
  document.getElementById('searchField').value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="searchGroup">
  <input type="text" id="searchField">
  <button type="button" onclick="clearInput()">&times;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better than changing the method's name, use proper code by using an event listener instead of inline javascript.

```js
document.getElementById('clearSearch').addEventListener('click', clear);

function clear() {
  document.getElementById('searchField').value = '';
}
```

```html
<div class="searchGroup">
  <input type="text" id="searchField">
  <button type="button" id="clearSearch">&times;</button>
</div>
```